# RemoveChild frame animated MovieClip, will stop frame running?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

If I removeChild frame animated Movieclip, will it automatically stop running the frames inside it? Actually without calling mc.stop();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it will continue to play, reason being your movie clip is still a flash entity not on stage( so not for you), but for flash (yes he can see all).

So once you create a new movieclip, play it... you can add or remove the running clip without stopping. Basically changing parent doesn't change the state of the mc.

Answer (score 1):

No. The timeline will still play, and all the framescripts you might have in there will still be called.
Beware of the timeline devils :)